# How to make choices with the columns?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class question(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    choice1 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    choice2 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    choice3 = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=[choice1, choice2, choice3])
```

it's giving me this error:

***'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.***

but I don't know how to fix it?

***Thanks***

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit the choices are can the be hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
personnelsex_choices = (('M','Male'),('F','Female'))
personnelsex = models.CharField('Gender',max_length=1,choices=personnelsex_choices, null=True)
```

Your error message is asking for an `iterable`, which can be a `list`, `tuple`, or generator expression, etc. In this example it is a `tuple`. The tuple contains pairs of values. The first value of the pair is what gets stored in the field `personnelsex`, while the second, which is the 'human readable name' is what would be displayed to a user in an application.

In you code, there is no iterable containing the choices, only a single entry per choice when there must be two (in pairs), and there are no values, which are required.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use a `choices` field or create two different models for "Question" and "Choices" including a relationship between them.

If you create the `choices` field you won't able to insert multiple values for one question.

**Example:**

```
class question(models.Model):
    ANSWER_CHOICES = [
        (F, 'Freshman'),
        (S, 'Sophomore'),
        (J, 'Junior'),
        (S, 'Senior'),
    ]

    question = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    answer = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=ANSWER_CHOICES,
        null=TRUE,
    )
```

[Source of Choices Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices)

On the other hand, two different models will efficiently solve your problem.

**Example:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

[Source from Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models)